# naming entire column with the same class name

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to figure out if I can name an entire column with the same class name in a table, without having to name each individual cell. Any suggestions? Would I use `html`, `css` or `javascript` to do so? Is naming every cell the only way to do so?

Sorry if I post this in the wrong area, I'm new to this site and still trying to figure it out

Comment: you can use JS for it, the question remaining (for me) is why do you need to do this? - if it's only to apply special styles for it, you can use @epascarello's answer (no need to modify the html) - if it is for another reason, there might be other options

Comment: This is exactly what `colgroup` was built to address - if it is indeed just a style issue. [colgroup link](http://www.w3schools.com/TagS/tag_colgroup.asp)

Comment: I'm creating a calendar that I want my team to be able to update as needed. I'm having trouble with putting the correct numbers on the correct day. I'm sure there is an easier way than what I'm trying, any advice is welcomed....especially if there is a better way to do it than what I'm trying

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) pseudo class selector

```css
table tr td:nth-child(2) {
  background: #CCCCCC;
}
table tr td:nth-child(4) {
  background: #00FFEE;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1-1</td>
      <td>1-2</td>
      <td>1-3</td>
      <td>1-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2-1</td>
      <td>2-2</td>
      <td>2-3</td>
      <td>2-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3-1</td>
      <td>3-2</td>
      <td>3-3</td>
      <td>3-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4-1</td>
      <td>4-2</td>
      <td>4-3</td>
      <td>4-4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: while this applies a style to the 2nd and 4th columns, it does not give it a class name as OP is asking

Comment: @ochi I am assuming OP does not need the class name and did not realize they have the ability to select elements by index to apply styles. With a broad question it is hard to tell what OP's goal is. So I went with my gut.

Comment: fair enough, however, this is not explained in your answer ;) - imagine someone coming to the question (a day/week/month later), finding your answer and thinking it adds a class name to the column (when it doesn't) - it is very confusing to the newcomer.  Perhaps if you add an explanation to the answer, it will let the OP know what your code does and how it helps her?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a class to all the elements inside the table (the `td` elements in this case) you can do so with jQuery.

```js
$('td').addClass('my-class');
```

```css
.my-class{
color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1-1</td>
      <td>1-2</td>
      <td>1-3</td>
      <td>1-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2-1</td>
      <td>2-2</td>
      <td>2-3</td>
      <td>2-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3-1</td>
      <td>3-2</td>
      <td>3-3</td>
      <td>3-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4-1</td>
      <td>4-2</td>
      <td>4-3</td>
      <td>4-4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

With the example above you're basically telling jQuery to target all of the `td` elements and add your class to each one of them. However, this will apply the class to ALL the `td` elements in your DOM. If you want to apply the class only to the elements of a specific table, you can do so with:

```
$('.parent-class').find('td').addClass('your-class');
```

and you can add the parent-class to your `<tbody>` element of `table`. That way you [find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) all the elements that match.

Comment: thanks to @epascarello for the table. I hope you don't mind I used it.